# Are there any living traditions in the tantra and the agama today?

Tags: shiva, tantra, agamas, shakti, sri-vidya

May I request members,  if they get the time,  to guide on the following:

A large number of sampradaya-s in the Tantra and Agama are vanishing/have disappeared, and are now historical details.

But there are a few traditions that still have some adherents.

Apart from Sri Vidya, are there any other living traditions in vogue in the Tantra and the Agama?
There is the Shakta tradition in Bengal, but I gather it is dying.
Kashmir Saivism is practically gone out of Kashmir and the North.
The Kamakhya in Assam seems to be the only center of Shakta activity in the country other than the South - is this accurate to say?
In Maharashtra, and perhaps Gujarat, there could perhaps be some offshoots of the Dattatreya sampradaya. Is this reasonable to say?
How about Kerala?

I would appreciate any guidance in this matter.

Comment: Are you looking for Ashram / Guru names?

Comment: Aghori, Kapaalik (very few), Kamakhya tantriks, Nath yogis/Jogis, south indian traditions and many others still exist.